# Typeahead and Bloohdound with geojson markers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I want to use typeahead and bloodhound in a searchbox with a markers layer in geojson. Using a leaflet map and a searchbox sitting in a bootstrap navbar, a user can look up projects that are displayed on a map.

There is something I just dont understand in implementing bloodhound and typeahead. I have been unable to make it work.

First, I am using the array.push method to send info from the layer to an array using this code:

```
   function  onEachFeatureProj(feature, layer) {
var ProjPopup = 
    '<strong>Organization: ' + feature.properties.OrgName + '</strong>';
 ProjSearch.push({
    name: layer.feature.properties.OrgName,
    source: "CSJ 2014",
    id: L.stamp(layer),
    lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
    lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
  });
layer.bindPopup(ProjPopup);
}
```

Then, I define the bloodhound elements:

```
  var ProjBH = new Bloodhound({
name: "CSJ 2014",
datumTokenizer: function (d) {
  return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.OrgName);
},
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: ProjSearch,
limit: 10
  });
  ProjBH.initialize();
```

Finally, I start typeahead to send this to the searchbox:

```
  /* instantiate the typeahead UI */
  $("#searchbox").typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    highlight: true,
    hint: false
  }, {
    name: "CSJ 2014",
    displayKey: "name",
    source: ProjBH.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      header: "<h4 class='typeahead-header'>Projects</h4>",
      suggestion: Handlebars.compile(["{{name}}"].join(""))
    } 
  });
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/dzo5yg72/

**Edit**

I finally found the problem. I was missing some html element to receive the content:

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="feature-list">
        <tbody class="list"></tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Immediately on load, you had a JS error thrown of 
`Uncaught Error: invalid dataset name: CSJ 2014` . 
That is because typeahead.js does not allows spaces in `name`. 
*"Must only consist of underscores, dashes, letters (a-z), and numbers."*
See docs at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets
Why don't you switch it to `CSJ_2014`?

Comment: Good point. I tried changing the name and I don't get a different result.

Comment: what is the exact behavior you are looking for here?where is your code which shows/hides map features based on bloodhound queries?

Comment: What Im trying to do is this: a user enters text in the search box to find specific projects from a markers layer and have suggestions shown in a list to click on. The example I have on jsfiddle tries to get there.

Comment: Here's a fork with a start - http://jsfiddle.net/4b3q0u78/ . Notice how you have some css issues to resolve with having bloodhound in the navbar as it begins to show hints.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the main problem: I was missing some html code to receive the info from bloodhound and typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. I was missing some html element to receive the content:

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="feature-list">
    <tbody class="list"></tbody>
 </table>
```